# update jupyter notebook to python 3.7

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have python installed versions 3.73 but for jupyter notebook I have `3.6.8`. How to upgrade python to version 3.7+ on jupyter notebook?

I tried:

```
 conda update jupyter

 conda upgrade notebook
```

when I type in the terminal in virtual env python -V I get 3.73
but when I check it in jupyter:

```
 from platform import python_version
 print(python_version())
```

I get `3.6.8`.

Comment: try updating jupyter_core and jupyter_client to their latest version:

`conda install jupyter_core jupyter_client`

Comment: Any news how to update ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below code :

```
conda install ipython jupyter
```

I ran this command in Anaconda Prompt and it worked. Don't forget to restart the jupyter notebook after the installation.